# Multiply string values

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
$price = "15.50";
```

And I would like to multiply it. Ex:

```
$price*$amount;
```

I tried something like this:

```
$Total = floatval($price)*$amount;
```

But I always get "30" as return. How can I code to get "31.00"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried to (float)$price. But it returns "30" too...

Comment: make `$amount` a float as well

Comment: Assuming `$amount` is an integer `2`, then `$Total` is casted to an integer `30`.  If you float `$amount`, then it will be `15.50 * 2.0 = 31.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$fltAmount = floatval($amount);
$fltPrice = floatval($price);
$Total = $fltAmount*$fltPrice
```

I found the answer here! http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `float` as datatype. This gets easily typecasted into `int`. So, do this!

```
$Total = floatval($amount) * floatval($price);
```